# How to draw a circle in custom view on button click

Tags: android, view, onclick, custom-view

I have a button called add that needs to draw a point on my custom view when clicked, and whenever the button is clicked it doesn't run the code..

I've implemented OnClickListener in my custom view, but it still has issues. I'm still new to custom views, so any help would be appreciated.

LineGraphView.Java

```
public class LineGraphView extends View implements View.OnClickListener {

int mPointColor, mMaxColor, mLineColor;
Paint mPointPaint, mMaxPaint, mLinePaint, mBodyPaint, mAxisPaint, 
 mTextPaint;
float mCircleRadius;

public LineGraphView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setOnClickListener(this);

    TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, 
     R.styleable.LineGraphView);
    mPointColor = array.getColor(R.styleable.LineGraphView_pointColor, 
    Color.GRAY);
    mMaxColor = array.getColor(R.styleable.LineGraphView_maxColor, 
    Color.BLUE);
    mLineColor = array.getColor(R.styleable.LineGraphView_lineColor, 
  Color.BLUE);

    array.recycle();

    initPaints();
}

private void initPaints() {
    mPointPaint = new Paint();
    mPointPaint.setColor(mPointColor);

    mMaxPaint = new Paint();
    mMaxPaint.setColor(mMaxColor);

    mLinePaint = new Paint();
    mLinePaint.setColor(mLineColor);

    mBodyPaint = new Paint();
    mBodyPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    mAxisPaint = new Paint();
    mAxisPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mAxisPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);

    mTextPaint = new Paint();
    mTextPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mTextPaint.setTextSize(30);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    //X Axis
    canvas.drawLine(50, dpToPx(190), dpToPx(400), dpToPx(190),mAxisPaint);
    //Y Axis
    canvas.drawLine(50,50,50,dpToPx(190),mAxisPaint);

    int centerX = getWidth()/2;
    //TESTING draw points
    //canvas.drawCircle(centerX, 100, 20, mPointPaint);

    canvas.drawText("0",25,dpToPx(190),mTextPaint);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button add = findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
    //if (v==add) {
        Canvas canvas=new Canvas();
        canvas.drawCircle(50,50,50,mPointPaint);
        invalidate();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Add button clicked!!",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //}
}

//Convert dp to pixels
private int dpToPx(int dpValue) {
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dpValue, getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
//Round number up to nearest multiple input
int round(double num, int multipleOf){
    return (int)Math.ceil(num/multipleOf) * multipleOf;
}
}
```

My Activitymain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.mdadi.graphview.LineGraphView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/graphView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/date"
    android:id="@+id/date_desc"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/students_desc"
    android:layout_below="@+id/graphView" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/graphView"
    android:id="@+id/date_input"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/date_desc"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/students"
    android:id="@+id/students_desc"
    android:layout_below="@+id/date_input"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/students_input"
    android:layout_below="@+id/date_input"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/students_desc"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/add"
    android:layout_below="@+id/date_input"
    android:id="@+id/addBtn"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/clear"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/addBtn"
    android:id="@+id/clear"
    android:layout_below="@+id/date_input"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/show_lines"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/select_show_lines"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addBtn"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/highlight_integral"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/show_lines"
    android:text="@string/select_highlight_integral"/>

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/radius_adjuster"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:min="5"
    android:max="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/highlight_integral"
    />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You should `drawCircle` inside `onDraw` . On button Click set a Global Flag to draw circle or not and call ` invalidate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:** This block code make your app does not work.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button add = findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
    //if (v==add) {
        Canvas canvas=new Canvas();
        canvas.drawCircle(50,50,50,mPointPaint);
        invalidate();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Add button clicked!!",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //}
}
```

You are creating a new canvas and draw on it instead of current view's canvas.

**Solution:** You can do the following steps

**Step 1:** Define a **Circle** class inside the custom view class.

```
public class LineGraphView extends View implements View.OnClickListener {

...

class Circle {
    float cx;
    float cy;
    float radius;
}

Circle mCircle;

...

}
```

**Step 2:** Modify **onDraw()** method

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    //X Axis
    canvas.drawLine(50, dpToPx(190), dpToPx(400), dpToPx(190), mAxisPaint);
    //Y Axis
    canvas.drawLine(50, 50, 50, dpToPx(190), mAxisPaint);

    int centerX = getWidth() / 2;
    //TESTING draw points
    //canvas.drawCircle(centerX, 100, 20, mPointPaint);

    canvas.drawText("0", 25, dpToPx(190), mTextPaint);

    // Add this line.
    if (mCircle != null) {
        canvas.drawCircle(mCircle.cx, mCircle.cy, mCircle.radius, mPointPaint);
    }
}
```

**Step 3:** Change code in **onClick()** method.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (mCircle == null) {
        mCircle = new Circle();
    }
    mCircle.cx = 50;
    mCircle.cy = 50;
    mCircle.radius = 50;

    // This will call onDraw() method under the hood.
    invalidate();

    // For debugging.
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Add button clicked!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```